# Docker cache for nodemodules and python requirements

Tags: python, node.js, linux, docker

I have a dockerfile and i'm trying to use COPY . .

I have a dockerfile and I've gave my best attempt at copying local dependancies over and using the docker cache.

Right now I have the python requirements using the cache but not the node_modules.

```
FROM itsspeed/ubuntu-16.04-python
#FROM python:2.7-stretch
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
 --no-install-recommends curl sudo apt-transport-https
RUN apt-get install libssl-dev -y
RUN python --version

#VOLUME "/usr/local/app"

# Set up C++ dev env
RUN apt-get update && \
   apt-get dist-upgrade -y && \
   apt-get install gcc-multilib g++-multilib cmake wget -y  && \
   apt-get clean autoclean && \
   apt-get autoremove -y
   #wget -O /tmp/conan.deb -L https://github.com/conan-io/conan/releases/download/0.25.1/conan-ubuntu-64_0_25_1.deb && \
   #dpkg -i /tmp/conan.deb


RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_9.x | sudo -E bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential
#RUN apt-get install -y npm
RUN npm -v

RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/app

COPY nlu-server/requirements.txt /usr/local/app/nlu-server/requirements.txt
WORKDIR /usr/local/app/nlu-server
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /usr/local/app/nlu-server
WORKDIR /usr/local/app


COPY package.json /usr/local/app
RUN ["npm", "install"]
COPY . .



RUN echo "/usr/local/app/dm-prod/lib" > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/mythrift.conf
RUN echo "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu" >> /etc/ld.so.conf.d/mythrift.conf
RUN echo "/usr/local/lib64" >> /etc/ld.so.conf.d/mythrift.conf
RUN ldconfig

EXPOSE 9090
RUN chmod +x dm-prod/dm3
RUN ldd dm-prod/dm3
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "dm-prod/dm3"]
RUN ["chmod", "777", "policy"]
RUN ls -al .
CMD ["nodejs", "app.js"]
```

heres a snippit from docker output where i simply rebuild a container with no changes, as you can see the node modules are being re-installed. Good news though the python requirements are using cache.

```
Step 7/29 : RUN apt-get install -y nodejs
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 0dd67f16bd8d
Step 8/29 : RUN apt-get install -y build-essential
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 24c15ed4a512
Step 9/29 : RUN npm -v
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 2365c20cc909
Step 10/29 : RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 409fc9242250
Step 11/29 : COPY nlu-server/requirements.txt /usr/local/app/nlu-server/requirements.txt
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e8cb2304b033
Step 12/29 : WORKDIR /usr/local/app/nlu-server
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ae5f314a10d6
Step 13/29 : RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 348d0db50e78
Step 14/29 : COPY . /usr/local/app/nlu-server
 ---> bbe2e0efcf23
Step 15/29 : WORKDIR /usr/local/app
Removing intermediate container d9adf038e20f
 ---> 8cc90b3a07a6
Step 16/29 : COPY package.json /usr/local/app
 ---> 9c9a0b6b6e32
Step 17/29 : RUN ["npm", "install"]
 ---> Running in 10feae860449
npm WARN deprecated jade@1.11.0: Jade has been renamed to pug, please install the latest version of pug instead of jade
npm WARN deprecated formatio@1.1.1: This package is unmaintained. Use @sinonjs/formatio instead
npm WARN deprecated constantinople@3.0.2: Please update to at least constantinople 3.1.1
npm WARN deprecated transformers@2.1.0: Deprecated, use jstransformer

> nodemon@1.17.3 postinstall /usr/local/app/node_modules/nodemon
> node -e "console.log('\u001b[32mLove nodemon? You can now support the project via the open collective:\u001b[22m\u001b[39m\n > \u001b[96m\u001b[1mhttps://opencollective.com/nodemon/donate\u001b[0m\n')" || exit 0

Love nodemon? You can now support the project via the open collective:
 > https://opencollective.com/nodemon/donate

npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

added 919 packages in 18.65s
Removing intermediate container 10feae860449
 ---> d506ee33621f
Step 18/29 : COPY . .
 ---> 7606470b8292
```

Comment: See: [Building Efficient Dockerfiles - Node.js](http://bitjudo.com/blog/2014/03/13/building-efficient-dockerfiles-node-dot-js/)

Comment: Are you making changes to the `package.json` file? If so, the cached layer will not be used.

Comment: @Yuankun i've added my console output. i'm not changing the package.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any and all curious, those who have a few layers of dependencies they need cached.

the lines around here were I install the node modules

```
WORKDIR /usr/local/app


COPY package.json /usr/local/app
RUN ["npm", "install"]
COPY . .
```

I needed to actually reset the working directory to root to copy over package json.

```
WORKDIR /
COPY package.json /usr/local/app/package.json
WORKDIR /usr/local/app
RUN ["npm", "install"]
COPY . .
```

The prior code was copying from the same folder to the same folder, essentially making it a new, changed file, triggering the npm install.
Best